# Confusion about proof of necessary + sufficient condition for $\theta \in \mathbb{C}$ to be an algebraic integer

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, integers

I am confused about a step in a proof of the following statement in Stewart Tall's ANT book:

$\theta \in \mathbb{C}$ is an algebraic integer if and only if the additive group $G$ generated by powers of $\theta$ is finite.

The "if" part of the proof proceeds as follows: The subgroup $\Gamma$ of $G$ generated by $1, \theta, \ldots, \theta^n$ must be finitely generated. Call the generators $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$. Each $v_i$ is a polynomial in $\theta$ with integer coefficients, so $\theta v_i$ is also such a polynomial. Hence there exist integers $b_{ij}$ such that
$$\theta v_i = \sum_{j=1}^{n} b_{ij}v_j.$$
This last step is what throws me. How is it that $\theta v_i$ has such an expression? It seems to rely on the fact that the $v_i$ generate $\Gamma$. But $\Gamma$ is additive, so I see no reason why the product $\theta v_i$ is necessarily in $\Gamma$. Any clarification would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Say $v_i=a_0+a_1\theta +a_2 \theta^2+\cdots.$ Then $\theta v_i=a_0 \theta + a_1 \theta^2 + \cdots$ is also a polynomial in $\theta$ with integer coefficients. I think the trick needed here is to actually "multiply through" by the $\theta$ as just done, so the result is definitely one of the polynomials in $\theta$ with integer coefficients. Maybe the confusion is in thinking of the $\theta$ in the expression $\theta v_i$ as playing the role of a scalar.

Comment: I still don't understand why each $\theta v_i$ can necessarily be expressed in terms of the $v_i$. The $v_i$ generate $\Gamma$ so the degrees of the $v_i$ need not be higher than $n$. But at least one of the $v_i$ needs to have degree $n$ since $theta^n \in \Gamma$. But if you multiply that one by $\theta$ you will get a degree $n + 1$ polynomial. Why should that be expressible in terms of the $v_i$? Thanks

Comment: In the "if" part of the proof, does Tall's proof *assume* the group $G$ generated by powers of $\theta$ is finitely generated? And if so does it also assume $G$ is generated by $1, \theta, \theta^2,\cdots, \theta^n$? If so then since $\theta^{n+1}$ lies in $G$ it can be expressed as an integer combination of the powers from 0th up to nth power of $\theta$ and so when the last term $a_n\theta^{n+1}$ of $\theta v_i$ is encountered it can be expressed as just outlined, and that can be added to the previous terms of $\theta u_i$ whose degrees are less than $n$.

Comment: It assumes $G$ is finitely generated and assumes that $\Gamma$ is some subgroup of $G$ generated by $\{1, \theta, \ldots, \theta^n\}$. It does not assume that $\{1, \theta, \ldots, \theta^n\}$ generates the whole group.

Comment: Then in the above one should say that $\theta^{n+1}$ lies in $\Gamma$ with the same idea applied to the term $a_n \theta^{n+1}$ now (since in $\Gamma$) expresses it in $\Gamma$ as a linear integer coefficient combination of the powers of $\theta$ which generate $\Gamma.$